# Inexistence of periodic orbits using Bendixson's criterion

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $X:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a linear map.
Prove that there is $\delta>0$ such that for all field $Y$ over $\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfying:
$$ \underset{x\in\mathbb{R}^2}{\sup} \left\Vert Y(x) \right\Vert <\delta $$ and
$$ \underset{\left\Vert x\right\Vert\leq1}{\sup} \left\Vert \mathrm{D}Y(x) \right\Vert <\delta $$
The field $X+Y$ does not admit any periodic solution.

==================================================================

In the first part of the exercise I had to prove the following version of the Bendixson's criterion:
"Let $X:U\subset\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a $\mathcal{C}^1$ field on $U$ a simply connected open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. If $\forall x\in U,\,\mathrm{div} X \neq 0$, then $X$ does not admit any periodic orbit in $U$"

What I did:

$X+Y$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$ since $X$ is linear and $\mathrm{D}Y$ is continuous.

Now I can use the criterion if I prove $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^2, \mathrm{div} \left(X+Y\right)(x) \neq 0$

Since $X$ is linear: $X(x_1, x_2)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}a & b \\ c & d \end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{c} x_1\\x_2 \end{array}\right)$, so $\mathrm{div} X(x) = a + d$

Here I'm stuck trying to prove $\boxed{ \frac{\partial Y_1}{\partial x_1} (x) + \frac{\partial Y_2}{\partial x_2} (x) \neq -a-d}$

EDIT:

For $\left\Vert x \right\Vert\leq 1,\, \left| \mathrm{div} Y(x) \right|=\left| \mathrm{TrD} Y(x) \right|\leq \left\Vert \mathrm{Tr} \right\Vert\left\Vert \mathrm{D}Y(x) \right\Vert \leq  \left\Vert \mathrm{Tr} \right\Vert\delta<\left| a+d \right|$ for a good choice of $\delta$.

So we are sure there is no periodic orbit in the unit disk.

But I still don't get how to conclude outside of the unit disk.

Answer (score 0):

If $a+d \neq 0$ (which is the assumption that $\text{div}(X) \neq 0$) and the Jacobian of $Y$ has small enough norm, then the divergence of $Y$ (that is, the trace of the Jacobian of $Y$) cannot be $-a-d$.

If this is not clear, one way to see it is to notice that the trace operator is a bounded linear functional. So there exists $M>0$ such that for any $\delta>0$, if $\mathcal{A}=B_\delta(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$, then $Tr(\mathcal{A}) \subset (-M\delta,M\delta)$.

Does that solve your problem?

By the way, +1 for showing your work. I would not have been able to help without your work to start from (I know rather little about dynamics).

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations. Nevertheless there are still some problems: I did not assume $\mathrm{div} \neq 0$, only that $X$ is linear sorry if I was misleading. Plus your proof does not use the upper bound on $\left \Vert Y \right\Vert$. But Thank you for the trace of the Jacobian I had forgotten this property.

Comment: If $\text{div}(X)=0$ then can't you have a counterexample in the form of $Y \equiv 0$? To be precise, if $X$ is the linear map corresponding to $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $Y \equiv 0$ then you should have periodic solutions, correct? An even more trivial case follows if you consider $X \equiv 0$.

Comment: You almost completely convinced me!  The remaining issue being you don't use the upper bound on $\left\Vert Y \right\Vert$, which seems odd.

Comment: I think there is a major issue in your proof when you assume "the Jacobian of $Y$ has small enough norm". We don't know any upperbound for $\left\Vert x \right\Vert >1$. Anything can happen.

Comment: @lafaillette You're right. But out there $X$ is "large" while $Y$ is small. ($X$ is not necessarily large everywhere, but a periodic trajectory would pass through all angles, so it would be large on a "large" part of such a trajectory.)

Comment: I am not sure to understand. Anyway for a fixed $X$ we can choose $Y$ such that when $\left\Vert x \right\Vert>1$ $\left\Vert \mathrm{div} Y(x)\right\Vert > a+d$. So I'm really puzzled...

Comment: Roughly speaking if $X$ is large, $\delta$ is small, and $\text{div}(Y)$ is large, then $Y$ must be quite oscillatory. For instance it could be a mollification of $\delta(\sin(x/\varepsilon)+\sin(y/\varepsilon)) 1_{B(0,1)}(x,y)/2$. Can such a $Y$ create a periodic trajectory?

Comment: I think the statement is not true. If I fix $\delta$, $Y(x,y)=(\frac{\delta}{4} \sin(x^2), 0)$ is a counter example I think because $\mathrm{div} Y(x,y)$ take every values in $\mathbb{R}$